Help to open tibia on ubuntu 24.04. QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
I'm trying to install tibia on my computer. I always receive the following error when I try to run the program. Can someone help me?
input:
sudo ./Tibia

output:QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root

What is Tibia? The error is probably because you are trying to run it with sudo, which uses a restricted environment that doesn't include the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR variable.
